# Encountering problems with JSFiddle code

Tags: error-handling

I have recently written a piece of code that checks temperature over a period of time for some course work. i wrote the program using  different bits of code but cannot find the issue to some of the problems i am encountering.

I was just wondering if anyone can see any obvious errors that i am missing and could help out with some information int he right direction.

[Link to the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20037805/g7m0dso3/13/)

```
//Counting the average temperatures in a day
//needs debugged!!!

var temperatures = [];
var total = 0;

function getCity() {
    //get the locale to help with the display
    city = prompt("Enter your city >> ");
}

function getNumDays() {
    number =  prompt("How many days in the study? Enter 1 - 10");
    while ((number < 1) || (number > 10) ||( isNaN(number) === true)) {
    alert ("Invalid input!");
        number = prompt ("Enter again, 1 - 10 >> ");}
    return number;
    }

function getTemps(numDays) {
    total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numDays; i++) {
        next = prompt ("Enter the temperature for day " + (i+1));
        next = parseint(next);
        while (isNaN(next)===true) {
            next = 0;
            next = prompt ("Error in input! Try again >>");
            next = parseInt(next);}
        temperatures.push(next);      
    }
    total = total + next;
    return temperatures; 
}

function calcAverage(total, numDays) {
    average = total / numDays;
    return average;
    }

function showStatistics(city, average, numdays) {
    alert ("The average daily temperature for "+ city +  " is " + average.toFixed(2) + " measured over " + numDays + " days." );
}

//main program
city = getCity();
numDays = getNumDays();
temperatures = getTemps(numDays);
Average = calcAverage(total, numDays);
showStatistics(city, average, numDays);
```

Comment: You need to return the city from `getCity()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getCity() {
    //get the locale to help with the display
    city = prompt("Enter your city >> ");
}

//main program
city = getCity();
```

Looks like you're missing a return statement.

Additionally, the line `total = total + next;` seems to be out of place: I imagine the `total` to be the `total` of the `temperatures`, not `0 + temperatureOfLastDay`.